# 'git push origin master' freezes

Tags: git, github

When pushing onto GitHub, git freezes and won't allow me to use my password.

```
Johndoe (master) reflections $ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': Johndoe38 
Password for 'https://Johndoe38@github.com': *
```

Where I have the asterisk there is a grey box with a white circle inside. 
It won't allow me to type my pass, q out, esc, anything. I've already quit and restarted the terminal...

Comment: Type your password and hit enter. Passwords in terminal aren't displayed

Comment: wow... that simple. Thanks!

Comment: let me move the comment into an anwser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type your password and hit enter.

Passwords in terminal aren't displayed this is the way most terminal uses to not display a password while typing.